# This my logical data digram ,is this digram is correct?

Tags: database, data-modeling

this my logical data diagram to my Android application, I really don't know if this draw is correct or no .. some help please {this is }

[image: Android app diagram]

Comment: Your diagram is a physical model diagram, showing tables and foreign key constraints. A logical model diagram would represent functional dependencies, candidate keys and relations.

Answer (score 0):

The tables and relations look correct.

But you need to normalize further please go through this book

http://cir.dcs.uni-pannon.hu/cikkek/Database_Normalization.pdf